# Android how to handle button names in array

Tags: android

I have a couple of buttons like

```
font1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fontsize1);
font2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fontsize2);
```

When I click on a button I want to change its textcolor and also change the textcolor of the rest of the buttons. Of course I do not want to write many lines best practice is a loop.

```
    font1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SaveFontSize("fontsize", "font1");
            font1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(color_active));
            font1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fonturesgreen);
            }
        }

        });
```

I created a list:

```
List<String> fontarray = Arrays.asList("font1", "font2", "font3", "font4", "font5");
```

And in the loop I tried to do this:

```
  for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    fontarray.get(i).setTextColor(Color.parseColor(color_active));
    }
```

This gives me an error, since fontarray.get(i) is a String, not a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a list of buttons as a **class member** instead:

```
List<Button> buttonArray = new ArrayList<Button>();
```

And in the `onCreate()`:

```
buttonArray.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.fontsize1));
// same for the rest
```

now you can access it like that:

```
for (int i=0; i < buttonArray.length(); i++) {
    buttonArray.get(i).setTextColor(Color.parseColor(color_active));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can actually iterate through controls in your layout, find buttons and compare their names  (or other attributes you want) with the values stored in your `List<String>`:

```
LinearLayout yourLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.yourLayout);

for (int i = 0; i < yourLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
    Object block = yourLayout.getChildAt(i);
    if (block instanceof Button) {
        Button btn = (Button)block;
        // do something with the button
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do it this way:

```
List<Button> fontarray = Arrays.asList(font1, font2, font3, font4, font5);
```